# Why is my neck bone influencing more than it should?

Tags: armature, weight-painting, pose-mode, weight-paint-mode

I am trying to get my armature (basic human rig) into position so I can pose my character. But when I get to the neck bone and fix the influence on this, it doesn't actually seem to be changing much. The neck bone is still influencing essentially the whole torso of the body when it clearly shouldn't... I have tried to remove all of the influence from the neck and still the same thing happens. What am I missing here?

[image: Weight paint influence][image: What it is actually doing]

Comment: Hello, maybe it's another bone that is above the neck that influences the body, hard to tell without the file, please share the fie here: https://blend-exchange.com/